Lunar Ascent Module - Center of Thrust
In a vacuum, in steady state, the Apollo Lunar Ascent Module is rated at 3500 lbF.
The combustion chamber is rated to run at 120 psia.  The throat/aperture from the Combustion chamber to the nozzle is 16.4 sqIn.  The Nozzle Exit aperture is 750 sqIn.
Applying basic fluid dynamics math here, the ratio of the nozzle exit aperture to the Combustion chamber throat, is 750 / 16.4 sqIn = 45.73.
So a reasonable estimate for the pressure at the exit of this nozzle will be:
Nozzle Exit psia =  (120 / 46.73) ==> 2.57 psia.
Therefore the Pressure Thrust of this configuration will be approximately:
2.57 psia * 750 sqIn ==>    1926 lbF  <== exerted uniformly along interior of the nozzle flare, and at the throat to the combustion chamber
The rest of the 3500 lbF of Thrust (about 1600 lbF) would then be Momentum Thrust (from fuel displacement)
This method is just trying to obtain an estimate with less than 20% error, by ignoring the more complex concept of fluid dynamics and 3000 Celsius combustion.
==
My question has two parts:

I'm certainly doing things wrong above.  What is the proper way to ESTIMATE (approximate) the Momentum Thrust vs. the Pressure Thrust? (the work tried to do above)

And then from this result, what is the proper way to then estimate the resulting "Center of Thrust"?


I would assume the center of thrust for Pressure Thrust is found by down-facing-component of the nozzle's interior surface, figuring uniform pressure perpendicular to all parts of this surface.
For the rest of the Center of Thrust, I would assume it might be centered near the top of the combustion chamber.  And this force would be attributed to "Momentum Thrust".
I couldn't find any good articles on calculating Pressure Thrust and on calculating Center of Thrust.
Also, FYI, the fuel pressure feed line is 170 psia.  For sake of this math, I'm only looking for the "steady state" solution, without transient behavior.

You are making some terrible mistakes. I want to point out right from the start that pressure thrust and momentum thrust as you describe them are not two separate contributors, they are equal. They are both expressions of the same thing, and they should not be counted twice!
Now on to your question.
The largest contributor to a rocket engines thrust is the chamber pressure acting on a throat sized patch on the injector face. If you did your estimation by multiplying the chamber pressure by the throat area and then adding the exit pressure multiplied by the remaining nozzle exit area, you would get a much closer answer!
But the simplest way to estimate a rocket's thrust is with the thrust coefficient:
$$F = c_fP_cA_t = \dot{m}v_e +\left(P_e -P_a \right)A_e = \int P_x ~dA$$
You see that the thrust ($F$) is directly proportional to the product of chamber pressure ($P_c$) and throat area ($A_t$). But it is not one-to-one. It is scaled by the thrust coefficient ($c_f$). I also include here the classic rocket thrust equation that breaks down into a momentum term ($\dot{m}v_e$) and a pressure term ($\Delta PA_e)$. When you hear someone refer to 'pressure' thrust and 'momentum thrust', these are the terms they are talking about (and they are indeed different from one another).
The pressure thrust you describe (i.e. the integrated axial pressure force acting on the engine walls) I include at the end of that equation. You can see that it is directly equal to the thrust. To be precise, the integral there is the physical accounting for thrust, and the middle equation accounts for the momentum that must be imparted into the exhaust by the pressure distribution. The conservation of momentum tells us these are equal, but it is much easier to measure, meter, and compute momentum than pressure distributions because the former has no dependance on geometry. Note that the pressure integral must be evaluated on the inside and outside of the engine!
For a more detailed breakdown about the equality between the momentum based and pressure based thrust formulations, check out this answer.
Let us return to the thrust coefficient and the lunar ascent module. The thrust coefficient accounts for unideal expansion. I give a detailed breakdown of its calculation in this answer. The values you gave for throat and exit area give an expansion ratio of 45.7, this paired with a vacuum ambient pressure gives a thrust coefficient of about 1.9.
With the thrust coefficient, we can finally (and simply) compute the thrust as 1.9 multiplied by 120 psi multiplied by 16.4 square inches, giving 3,740 pounds of thrust. This is very close to wikipedia's cited thrust value of 3,500 pounds. The delta could easily be explained by the fact that I haphazardly picked the thrust coefficient off a chart computed with inappropriate gas properties. If you compute the thrust coefficient specifically for this engine, the answer would become more precise.
A final note!  You cannot just assume that the pressure ratio across the nozzle will be equal to the area ratio!  Though the linked questions touch on that aspect, so I will leave it at that.
Just kidding, I will address the center of thrust question. The pressure distributions in most rocket engines are mostly axisymmetric, placing the center of thrust colinear with the engines symmetry axis. In any case, an integral of the pressure force will give a resultant vector that will tell you the location and direction of the net thrust. If you'd like to play around without doing truly nasty integrations, you might look into the equations for center of gravity and draw an analogy between mass and pressure.

This should help you out with some basics:
https://www.clavius.org/techlmstab.html
https://www.clavius.org/img/lmfront.gif

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
